# Wampserver en anaranjado en windows 10

Tags: php, wampserver

al instalar wampserver aparece el icono anaranjado elimin'e el skype que supuestamente usa el puerto 80, hago un test del puerto 80 y aparece:
Port 80 is not found associated with TCP PROTOCOL
you port 80 seems not actually used
unable to initiate a socket connection
error number:1061 - No se puede establecer conexion ya que el equipo de destino denego expresamente dicha conexion.
Trato de conectar al puerto 82 o 8080 y pasa lo mismot
apliqu'e : iisreset -stop y no soluciona por favor si me pueden ayudar, gracias

Comment: La última vez que use Wampserver requería [VC++ redist update 4](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170#visual-studio-2012-vc-110-update-4), ¿lo instalaste? Si te pide alguna versión más reciente, desde ese mismo enlace lo puedes buscar y descargar.

Comment: Tal vez hubo un problema al crear el servicio de Apache y debes hacerlo por tu cuenta: Clic en el icono de Wampserver -> Apache 2.x.x -> Service administration ‘wampapache64’ > Install Service. Después reinicias todos los servicios y ya debería funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Skype utiliza por defecto los puertos 80 y 443 como puertos alternativos para los conexiones entrantes, pero es algo que podemos desactivar de una forma sencilla.

**Solución 1**

1. Accede al menú de » Herramientas > Opciones «
2. Haz click en la pestaña de » Avanzadas » y selecciona » Conexión «
3. Desactiva » Usar puerto 80 y 443 como alternativas para las conexiones entrantes «

**Solucion 2**
Si queremos usar WampServer en un entorno de desarrollo, es probable que no necesites utilizar el puerto 80. Apache podría estar configurado en otro puerto alternativo, como por ejemplo el 8080.

1. Haz click sobre el icono de WampServer Wampserver
2. Entra en la carpeta de Apache y haz click sobre » httpd.conf «. Se abrirá un notepad con la configuración de Apache
3. Busca la cadena de texto » Listen 80 » y modifícala por » Listen 8080 «
   Guarda los cambios y reinicia WampServer haciendo click en » Restart All Services «.

Si todo ha ido bien, el icono de Wamp ahora debería de estar en verde, indicando que todos los servicios se están ejecutando correctamente.

Comment: El puerto 80 no esta siendo usado , revise con  netstat  -ano y al cambiar en httpd.conf  listen 8080 pasa lo mismo.. ??